# How to use currency on type=Number when value is using computed data?

Tags: vue.js, input, decimal

Okay, so I have an input field with below code and wanting use decimals to look like 10,000 for 100000.

```
input#payment.form-control(type='number'
                           v-model='payment')
```

Payment for v-model is coming from computed data using mixin and updates new value using methods.

```
computed:{
  get () { return this.NameOfMixin.payment },
  set (value) {this.updateStore('payment', value)}
},
methods: {
  updateStore(field, value) {
    ...
  }
}
```

All the code above are working fine except now I want to display decimals and use a plain number for updating the store.

I have tried using creating methods to convert the value to decimals and v-money but nothing worked as I wished.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in here?

Comment: I am trying to display the amount with decimals instead of a plain number. As users change the input value, I would like to update the store without decimals.

Comment: You can easily do it with the help of the `filters`

Comment: Can I do `filters` when type=number?

Comment: check this out: https://codepen.io/aegypius/pen/qNQrXw

Comment: I just added filter globally and added `| currencyDisplay` after my v-model but getting `ShareApplication.vue?d6ba:21 Uncaught Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Assigning to rvalue (1:4903)` this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share jsFiddle for that?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/myjhk1105/fzvaj3td/2/

Comment: add filter in your computed property like this: https://jsfiddle.net/varit05/npfvL0my/ and check

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/myjhk1105/fzvaj3td/7/ I still get the same error

Comment: "TypeError: this.$options.filters.currencyDisplay is not a function" Now that I add filter in my computed property and delete `|currencyDisplay` from v-model, I get that message. I'm not sure why it says it is not a function when I added them to filters

Comment: It is working for me. please check once more at your end.